# After adding excel jar, When execute script following warning occurs in console. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN
```

See for [more info.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig)

Answer (score 1):

Add the location of the standard `log4j.properties` file to the Classpath in Eclipse.

OR

Put `BasicConfigurator.configure();` to main method.